# How to deal with dynamic subject in javamail?

Tags: jakarta-mail

I am trying to download the attachments from gmail account which works fine with exact subject line , but it is not working same when dynamic date is in the subject line.  E.G. `subjectname_20170731`. Here the `20170731` part is dynamic.  Here is the code used for the search:

```
SearchTerm subj = new SubjectTerm('subjectname'); 
SearchTerm currentDate = new ReceivedDateTerm(ComparisonTerm.EQ, currentDate); 
SearchTerm searchmail = new AndTerm(subj, currentDate); 
messages = folderInbox.search(searchmail);
```

Is there any way we can specify the static part and javamail downloads the attachmensts?

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand your problem.  What does the subject line have to do with the ability to download attachments?  Can you not find the right message because of the subject line?  Are you using the [Folder.search](https://javaee.github.io/javamail/docs/api/javax/mail/Folder.html#search-javax.mail.search.SearchTerm-) method with a [SubjectTerm](https://javaee.github.io/javamail/docs/api/javax/mail/search/SubjectTerm.html)?

Comment: yes , i'm searching for mail with the subject line , when i get the mail i download the attachments

Comment: Provide your code that you suspect causes an issue.

Comment: The SubjectTerm should only match a subset of the subject line, so you should be able to search for the part of the subject that does not include the date and does not change.  If you're doing that and it's not working, we need to see the code and the [JavaMail debug output](https://javaee.github.io/javamail/FAQ#debug) showing the failure.

Comment: SearchTerm subj = new SubjectTerm('subjectname');
SearchTerm currentDate = new ReceivedDateTerm(ComparisonTerm.EQ, currentDate);
SearchTerm searchmail = new AndTerm(subj, currentDate);
messages = folderInbox.search(searchmail);

actual mail subject line is "subjectname_20170731" here '20170731' part is dynamic

Answer (score 0):

As [Bill-Shannon](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1040885/bill-shannon) explained:

> The [SubjectTerm](https://javaee.github.io/javamail/docs/api/javax/mail/search/SubjectTerm.html) should only match a subset of the subject line, so you should be able to search for the part of the subject that does not include the date and does not change.

Get rid of your receive date term and change your code to:

```
messages = folderInbox.search(new SubjectTerm("subjectname_"));
```